# JavaScript: transform a text between <p> tags into a new one also between <p> tags (output)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to operate a transformation **onLoad** from a **<p> text </p>** in order to create a **<p> new modified text  </p>** (the point is I don't wanna use **textareas**) in simple javascript.

Here is what I've been trying to do (but it seems to work only with values coming from **textareas**) :

```
<script>
<?php include("js/roman.js"); ?>
function afficher(form2) {
    var testin = document.form2.TextToModify.value;
                 document.form2.NewModifiedText.value=hangul_to_roman(testin);
}
</script>

<div>
    <p name="TextToModify" value="input" onLoad="afficher(form2)">

        TEXT    

    </p>

    <p name="NewModifiedText" value="output">  

        <!-- NEW MODIFIED TEXT   -->

    </p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to get the first text between the "p" tags in order to proceed to the transformation ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Should all p tags be changed, or just one?

Comment: I just want to create what's contained between two last "p" tags by modifying the content in the two first "p".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- Better avoid inline event handlers.
- `p` elements can't have `name` nor `value` attributes.
- `document.form2.TextToModify` is a non standard way of accessing a form element. The standard way would be `document.forms.form2.elements.TextToModify`, but it won't work because `p` elements aren't [listed elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed).

```js
function hangul_to_roman(str){ return str; }
function afficher() {
  document.getElementById('NewModifiedText').innerHTML = hangul_to_roman(
    document.getElementById('TextToModify').innerHTML
  );
}

afficher(); // This must run after loading the DOM
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="TextToModify">
    TEXT
  </p>
  <p id="NewModifiedText">
    <!-- NEW MODIFIED TEXT -->
  </p>
</div>
```

The `hangul_to_roman` is only included here in order to make the code snippet runnable.

Note `afficher()` must be called after your elements have been loaded, e.g in a script placed just before closing `</body>`, or in an event listener of [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) events.

Comment: Thank you for your help, yet I couldn't get how to use the code. By the way, the function hangul_to_roman is actually already defined inside <?php include("js/roman.js"); ?>

Comment: @user2911849 Yes, I only included it here in order to make the code snippet runnable.

Comment: Though it seems to work perfectly in JSfiddle, thank you. Now I must  find a way to adapt it to my real webpage

Comment: @user2911849 The [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) is the Document Object Model. I meant that `afficher()` must be called after your elements have been loaded, e.g in a script placed just before closing `</body>`, or in an event listener of [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) events.